# How to redirect to another page using NodeJS

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I am new to NodeJS. I want the page to redirect to another page from a click on the first page. Could someone please help me to solve the problem. Any help will be appreciate. Here is the code

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/newPage.html', (req, res) => res.redirect('/newPage.html'))

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000', function(){
  console.log('App listening on Port %s', server.address().port);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>NodeJS - HTML/CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>NodeJS HTML and CSS Demo</h1>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maiores saepe quae debitis alias illum, animi sunt iste
    </p>

        <a href= "newPage.html">new page</a>

</body>
</html>
```

newPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>New page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is the new page</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/newPage', function(req,res){
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/newPage.html');
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000', function(){
  console.log('App listening on Port %s', server.address().port);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit');
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>NodeJS - HTML/CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>NodeJS HTML and CSS Demo</h1>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maiores saepe quae debitis alias illum, animi sunt iste
    </p>

        <a href="/newPage">new page</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Given that, I would recommend you to look at [express static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or [node-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static) if you are looking to have only a static website